# Convert 3d array to 2d array by merging data in each row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, array-merge

I need to flatten my subarrays of data to form a simpler / more shallow 2-dimensional array.  Each row should become a flat, indexed array of unique values.

Input array:

```
$response = [
    695 => [
        0 => [
            '00:00',
            '01:00',
            '01:30',
            '03:30',
            '04:00',
        ]
    ],
    700 => [ 
        1 => [
            '00:00',
            '00:30',
            '01:00',
            '01:30',
            '02:00',
        ],
        2 => [
            '00:00',
            '00:30',
            '09:00',
            '06:30',
            '07:00',                    
        ]
    ]
];
```

My current code:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($response as $key => $list) {
  $result[$key] = array_merge($result, $list);
}
var_export($result);
```

but this doesn't give the proper result.

Expected output:

```
array (
  695 => 
  array (
    0 => '00:00',
    1 => '01:00',
    2 => '01:30',
    3 => '03:30',
    4 => '04:00',
  ),
  700 => 
  array (
    0 => '00:00',
    1 => '00:30',
    2 => '01:00',
    3 => '01:30',
    4 => '02:00',
    5 => '09:00',
    6 => '06:30',
    7 => '07:00',
  ),
)
```

Comment: what is expected outcome ? and also what you tried so for?

Comment: *I want to merge the results based on the key* - which key? What have you tried?

Comment: I give this -1 later if this post didn't explain properly about the desired output.

Comment: This is an impossible output since based on key mentioned value will be overwritten.

Comment: you will never get your desired output because same indexes values will replaced . (new-one replace old one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

merge the array like this:

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
  $o = [];
  foreach($v as $val)
  {
    $o = array_merge($o, $val);
  }
  return array_values(array_unique($o));
}, $array);
```

Comment: check his output (it have same indexes)

Comment: how can the array have the same index

Comment: yes but i did not downvote. it still has index issue.use array_values before return.

Answer (score 0):

The modern equivalent of @LF00's answer is as follows.

Iterate each row without affecting the first level keys.  Merge (flatten) subsets of data, remove duplicates, then re-index the unique elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3d3gG))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($rows) =>
            array_values(
                array_unique(
                    array_merge(...$rows)
                )
            ),
        $array
    )
);
```